# Count up the date in reporting month

Tags: sql

```
Start Date  End Date 
4/1/2016    6/30/2016
3/1/2016    9/30/2016
4/25/2016   5/16/2016
2/1/2016    4/30/2016
```

If I want to calculate in these range in total days in April.

Output: Number of Day in Reporting Month

```
      30
      30
       6
      30
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used! (May dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/tome, so the answer will probably be product specific.)

Comment: Please state your RDBMS (vendor and version) and - as a hint - do not rely on culture specific datetime formats! One question: If the End-Date was in April you want the days up to this? Might be good to add an example for this case...

Comment: I didn't understand how you got this output :S

Comment: @sagi, number of April days included in the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server you might try something like this:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @mockTable TABLE(Start Date,[End] Date) 
INSERT INTO @mockTable VALUES
 ('4/1/2016','6/30/2016')
,('3/1/2016','9/30/2016')
,('4/25/2016','5/16/2016')
,('2/1/2016','4/30/2016');

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY
               ,CASE WHEN Start>{d'2016-04-01'} THEN Start ELSE {d'2016-04-01'} END
               ,CASE WHEN [End]<{d'2016-04-30'} THEN [End] ELSE {d'2016-04-30'} END
               ) +1 AS DaysInApril
FROM @mockTable
```

### EDIT: standard SQL

According @a_horse_with_no_name's comment this idea translated to standard SQL was:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN end_date <= date '2016-04-30' THEN end_date ELSE date '2016-04-30' END 
     - CASE WHEN start_date >= date '2016-04-01' THEN start_date else date '2016-04-01' END + 1 
FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: In standard SQL this would be: `SELECT case WHEN end_date <= date '2016-04-30' THEN end_date ELSE date '2016-04-30' END
       - CASE WHEN start_date >= date '2016-04-01' THEN start_date else date '2016-04-01' END + 1 from ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yes, that's better for a general answer. You might place this as answer yourself... I'll be there to vote it up :-)

Comment: I was playing around with a different (much more complex idea) while you answered. Your idea is much better, you should just add that as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Without hard coding the year (so it works for any year not just 2016), again SQL Server. Doesn't sanity check that start is before end or that the range covers April at all...

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (StartDate DATE,EndDate DATE);

INSERT INTO #Test (StartDate,EndDate) VALUES
('20160401', '20160630')
,('20160301', '20160930')
,('20160425', '20160516')
,('20160201', '20160430');


SELECT 
CASE WHEN MONTH(EndDate) > 4 THEN 30 ELSE DAY(EndDate) END - CASE WHEN MONTH(StartDate) < 4 THEN 1 ELSE DAY(StartDate) END + 1
FROM #Test
```